# Class inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, overloading

The following code will call the function F from class B, but can someone please explain to me why is that. Is it possible that methods from class B overload the ones from class V (because B is inherited from V)? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class V{
public: 
    void f(){ x+=2; cout << "V:"<< x;};
    int x;
};
class B: public virtual V{
public:
    void f(){ x+=3; cout << "B:"<< x;};
    int x;
};
class D: public B, virtual public V{
public:
    void g(){   x++;    f();    }
};
void main(){
    D ins;
    ins.x = 1;
    ins.g();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`B::f()` **hides** the method `V::f()`, this is known as **function hiding**.

Good Read:
[What's the meaning of, Warning: Derived::f(char) hides Base::f(double)?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/hiding-rule.html)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no overloading done there. As one answered above, f() of B simply hides f() of V, since D inherits from both B and V, and B is the most derived among the two, so it will take f() from B. And just to point that inheriting D from V is not necessary because V is contained from B already.